# When to create use a instance method vs when to pass object reference?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

If I want to do a DFS on a graph,

OPTION 1:
I can create a class Graph with a method dfs()

OR

OPTION 2:
I can create a 2 classes Graph and DFS and pass Graph object in constructor of DFS.

In general, when to use an instance method and when to opt to pass instance to another class's constructor ? Are there any rules of thumb ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use separate classes, to separate concerns of *being* a graph from *navigating* a graph.

Create an interface for a graph node, eg

```
interface Node<T> {
    T getValue();
    Set<Node<T>> getChildren();
}
```

And create an interface that navigates and searches graphs:

```
interface GraphSearcher<T> {
    Node<T> search(Node<T> root, T value();
}
```

Then create a DFS implementation:

```
class DfsGraphSearcher<T> {
    Node<T> search(Node<T> root, T value) {
        // DFS impl
    }
}
```

Further separating the responsibility from the implementation would allow you to swap in another (eg breadth first) impl without changing any client code, perhaps using an abstract factory.

Answer (score 0):

It will look good if you create 2 classes and pass Graph object into method of DFS class for search.